# Dynamic grid to allocate dynamic information from database

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I need to design a shape, that can be anything, depending on the side number that comes from the database. so, this shape can be a 
triangle, square, hexagon etc a beside this I will need to populate the free areas with other information become from database too. Everything dynamic. Anyone here has an idea of how I can prepare my code for all this dynamism.

Currently, I already built the dynamic shape and I can identify all the all vertices for each shape. However, I'm having struggle in to allocate the little boxes under each specific area. For each area, I can have 1 or 20 or X number of boxes and I need to allocate them in the specific area without overflowing or overlapping. Please see the image example.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZSCN.jpg

Anyone had built a similar thing?

Comment: your question is too broad for an efficient answer, what have you tryied, would shape-outside be useful here, .. ?

Comment: Hi @G-Cyr. Can you please see my image? the problem I'm having is to understand the logic that I should use to allocate the information that became from db.I can show the data if I point it for some area however the intention here is I will look at the db how many information I have for some area and just send back to the frontEnd and here everything should take a specific space without overflow or overlapping and for this logic is where I'm having problems. I already started making some calculations in my frontEnd but nothing worked until now.Do you have any experience on this kind of things?

Comment: what is your HTML structure to start with ? , what is the shape made from ?  are datas extracted wrapped in a single tag or is it again a structure (box, hx,p, img , ..) ? what is your document alike before data is injected ? What you ask is very similar to ask someone to do the whole thing from your idea and drawing. We can help a bit but not that much .

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me @G-Cyr. And please not think that I'm expecting to find here the solution for everything. I'm just trying to see if someone is able to understand the logic behind in finding the correct way to auto allocate information in a specific area. The little boxes are been returned already from db and then I'm converting them into SVG because quality view. But like I said my problem is to finding a way to auto allocate the information. I feel really lost where I should I start